# Enumeration of black-white edges on square lattices

Tags: combinatorics

In a square lattice of N sites, equal number of black and eight white sites are randomly distributed. Is there a general formula to enumerate the number of ways in which each arrangement of black-white edges arises?

Comment: Can you ask your question in more detail? What do you mean by "arrangement of black-white edges," exactly? Can you include a complete analysis of the problem for small $N$, so we can be sure we understand what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. For a square lattice of 16 sites,there are 1820 black-white edges in total, when 4 black sites are present randomly. However, when the edges are 8;10;12;14 and 16 there are 24;256;736;576 and 228 ways of obtaining these respectively. The precise partitioning of 1820 into the above five numbers seem non-trivial. Any analytical formula will be helpful in the thermodynamic properties of lattice models. In fact, N tends to infinity in the thermodynamic limit.Thanks